# How to find out which textfield was typed into by the user in a Java JtextField?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, matrix, jtextfield

I have the following code:

```
    int[] matrix = new int[9][9];

    (for int x = 0; x <= 8; x++){
        (for int y = 0; y <= 8; x++){
             JtextField matrix[x][y] = new JtextField(“Matrix" x + y)
             int[] coords = new int[2];
             coords[0] = x;
             coords[1] = y;
             matrix[x][y].putClientProperty("coords", coords);
             matrix[x][y].setText(game[x][y]);
         }
     }
```

After the loops end, I need a way of finding out which textfield the user typed into (the user also hits enter). So:
1. How do I check if a JtextField has been edited without knowing which one it is or its name?
2. How do I check which "coords" the textfield is positioned at? I have an idea of how to do it, but for some reason I cannot code it.

I feel like the answer is staring me right in the face, but its late, I'm tired, and I'm getting flustered. Thanks!

Comment: Add a Listener to your text fields to know which one the user types in.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you want to achieve.

If you're only interested in the end result, you could use an `ActionListener` (for when the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and a `FocusListener` for when they don't and leave the field any way (assuming you want to know this)

When the respective event occurs, you can inspect the `source` of the event by using `getSource`.  Now this returns `Object`, but you can use `instanceof` to determine if the object can be cast to a `JTextField`...

For example...

```
Object source = evt.getSource();
if (source instanceof JTextField) {
    JTextField field = (JTextField)source;
    int[] coords = field.getClientProperty("coords");
}
```

Take a look at [How to write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to write a Focus Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) for more details.

Depending on your needs, you could also take a look at [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)

Comment: Thanks - that was actually very useful information. I noticed embarrassing mistakes in my code after I posted, oh well

Comment: Glad to hear you got yourself a little closer to the end game ;)